# I get "bash: ...: No such file or directory" even though the executable is there

Tags: bash, executable

Operating system: Lubuntu 13.10, 64-bit.

I installed the [Seamonkey browser](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=seamonkey-2.22&os=linux&lang=en-US) from http://www.seamonkey-project.org/ following the instructions quoted below from http://www.seamonkey-project.org/doc/install-and-uninstall#install_linux

> To install SeaMonkey by downloading the tar.bz2 file:
>
> Create a directory named "seamonkey2" (mkdir seamonkey2) and change to that directory (cd seamonkey2).
>   Click the link on the site you're downloading SeaMonkey from to download the package (seamonkey-2.*.tar.bz2) file into the seamonkey2 directory.
>   Decompress the file with the following command:
>
> `tar jxvf seamonkey-2.*.tar.bz2`
>
> This creates a "seamonkey" directory under your seamonkey2 directory.
>   Change to the seamonkey directory (cd seamonkey).
>   Run SeaMonkey with the following command:
>
> `./seamonkey`

I followed the instructions but here is what I see with the following commands:

```
[05:28 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $ ll seam*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vasa1 vasa1 82816 Oct 29 08:23 seamonkey*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vasa1 vasa1 82820 Oct 29 08:23 seamonkey-bin*
```

---

```
[05:28 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $ seamonkey
bash: /home/vasa1/seamonkey2/seamonkey/seamonkey: No such file or directory
[05:28 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $ seamonkey-bin
bash: /home/vasa1/seamonkey2/seamonkey/seamonkey-bin: No such file or directory
[05:28 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $ ./seamonkey
bash: ./seamonkey: No such file or directory
[05:29 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $ ./seamonkey-bin
bash: ./seamonkey-bin: No such file or directory
[05:29 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $
```

So why is `bash` saying "No such file or directory" although the directory and files (seamonkey and seamonkey-bin) exist?

Here is the output of `cat /etc/environment`:

```
[05:38 PM] ~ $ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/vasa1/seamonkey2/seamonkey"
[05:38 PM] ~ $
```

Here is the output of `file seamonkey` and `ldd seamonkey`:

```
[06:29 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $ file seamonkey
seamonkey: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
[06:30 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $ ldd seamonkey
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7726000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76f6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf76f1000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf76ae000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf74fc000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7727000)
[06:31 PM] ~/seamonkey2/seamonkey $
```

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l` in that directory.  I think Cesar is correct, the files aren't executable.

Comment: I posted `ls -al for seam*` at the top of the code output in my question. Those are the relevant "executables" I think.

Comment: Try `file seamonkey` and `ldd seamonkey`...

Comment: @goldilocks, done. Please take a look.

Comment: What distro are you using?  Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit system?  If it's 32-bit, you may just need to install libstdc++ -- otherwise you need the 32-bit version of libstdc++.

Comment: Please update the title, or accept... and open a new question as your original issue was probably resolved by pstadler and now you have a different one.  Will help get your answers.

Comment: @goldilocks, it is 64-bit. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

You probably need the 32-bit libraries.

To install these on a Debian-based distribution (e.g. Ubuntu) run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: `apt-cache show ia32-libs` says it's a virtual package. apt-get suggested  `lib32z1`, `lib32ncurses5`, and  `lib32bz2-1.0` as replacements. I installed all three. I removed the seamonkey folder created by the previous `tar` operation and re-ran the tar command. Now, whether I try `seamonkey` or `seamonkey-bin` or `./seamonkey` or `./seamonkey-bin` I get this: `error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: For yum do `yum install libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.i686`

Comment: or search on that error there are a few solutions out there

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410444/183097

Comment: @pstadler, making so produces this error: "XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/seamonkey/libxul.so:
libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM." I have choosen to get the latest 64bit version from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/s/seamonkey-mozilla-build/

Answer (score 2):

Executable may not have execution permissions, try:

```
chmod +x seamonkey
chmod +x seamonkey-bin
```

and then run it.

Comment: I've shown the `ls -al` output at the start of the code segment. Both `seamonkey` and `seamonkey-bin` have `-rwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 0):

I searched the web for "can seamonkey be installed on 64-bit linux".

One of the results was this:
http://tutorialforlinux.com/2013/10/31/how-to-install-seamonkey-on-xubuntu-13-10-saucy-64bit-linux/. It pointed to http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/seamonkey/releases/2.22/contrib/seamonkey-2.22.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2.

That worked.